# Como invertir palabras individuales de un string con python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero invertir el string pero que me mantenga el orden de las palabras y solo invierta las letras como por ejemplo, si tengo

> Mi perro Renzo

Deberia de obtener

> iM orrep ozneR.

Pero cuando uso `[::-1]` me da este resultado:

> ozneR orrep iM

como puedo evitar invertir las palabras?

```
print (("Mi perro Renzo")[::-1])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Una forma más potente y robusta sería usando *expresiones regulares*. Para localizar palabras podemos usar el patrón `'\w+'`, que viene a indicar *"cualquier conjunto de letras, excluyendo los signos de puntuación y espacios"*:

```
import re

pat = re.compile("\w+")
print(pat.findall("¡Hola, Mundo!")
```

> ['Hola', 'Mundo']

Observar que el método de dividir la frase según los espacios nos habría colado la coma `','` y las exclamaciones `'¡!'` como parte de palabras.

El resultado de la expresión regular se puede usar para modificar directamente la cadena, ahorrándonos hacer más operaciones. Basta con pasar una función que invierta cada una de las palabras encontradas:

```
def invert(m):
    return m.group(0)[::-1]

resultado = pat.sub(invert, "¡Hola, Mundo!")
```

> '!aloH, odnuM!'

Answer (score 5):

Podrias intentar separar las palabras por espacios, luego invertirlas con `[::-1]` y finalmente volverlas a unir.

De esta manera:

```
' '.join([x[::-1] for x in ("Mi perro Renzo").split(' ')])
```

Primero, separamos todo en un arreglo con `("Mi perro Renzo").split(' ')`:

```
['Mi', 'perro', 'Renzo']
```

Luego a cada elemento del arreglo le aplicamos la inversion `[x[::-1] for x in ("Mi perro Renzo").split(' ')]`, resultando:

```
['iM', 'orrep', 'ozneR']
```

Y finalmente con `' '.join(...)` lo volvemos a unir todo por un espacio en blanco.

Answer (score 4):

Prueba esto

```
def reverse(phrase):
    return ' '.join(list(map(lambda x: x[::-1], phrase.split())))

print(reverse("Mi perro Renzo"))
```

Resultado

```
>>> iM orrep ozneR
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que una respuesta sencilla al problema que tienes es el siguiente:

1. Primero, se define un string llamado texto que contiene la frase "Hola a todos".

```
texto = "Hola a todos"
```

2. Luego, se utiliza el método split() para dividir el string en una
   lista de palabras, utilizando el espacio como separador. La lista
   resultante se almacena en la variable palabras.

```
palabras = texto.split()
```

3. A continuación, se inicia un bucle for que recorre cada elemento en la lista palabras. En cada iteración, el valor actual de palabra es la palabra actual en la lista.

```
for palabra in palabras:
```

4. Dentro del bucle, se utiliza una técnica llamada slicing (rebanado) para invertir el orden de los caracteres en la palabra actual. `palabra[::-1]` devuelve la palabra al revés. Finalmente, se utiliza la función `print()` para imprimir la palabra invertida en la consola, separando cada palabra con un espacio en blanco.

```
    print(palabra[::-1], end = ' ')
```

El resultado final de este código sería la siguiente salida en la consola:

```
aloH a sodot
```

aquí el código final:

```
texto = "Hola a todos"
palabras = texto.split()
for palabra in palabras:
    print(palabra[::-1], end = ' ')
```

Comment: Hola, te sugerimos revisar ; [CHATGPT está prohibido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/pol%c3%adtica-temporal-chatgpt-est%c3%a1-prohibido), saludos.

Answer (score -1):

```
def invertir(palabra):
    return palabra[::-1]

print(invertir(lola))
# o lo guardas en variable 
mi_palabra = invertir(lola)
print(f"esta es mi palabra invertida {mi_palabra}")
```

Comment: Saludos, por favor presiona [Editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/588741/edit) y agrega cómo el código que propones soluciona el problema de OP, las respuestas que son solo código son consideradas de baja calidad. ;)